# Fixed button at the bottom of the view

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to have a button (or buttons) at the bottom of the view, and everything else in a scrollview.

Whatever I do, I still can't have the button fixed at the bottom (the yellow rectangle at the bottom of the pic), I don't understand exactly why.

Here's the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/light_rose"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="Contact"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_title"
            android:background="#0000ff"
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/texthere"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="test test test test test test test test test test
        test test test test test test test test test test test test test
        test test test test test test test test test test test test test"
                android:textSize="35sp"></TextView>

        </ScrollView>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/footer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#ffff00">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/texthere2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="things in your footer here"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

See the screenshot:

[image]

Can anyone give me some hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of fixing a button on the bottom of your view just use bottom navigation bar. It's more appealing and attractive. You must have seen bottom tabs on whatsapp, facebook and linkedin etc apps. It's just like that and it's pretty easy too.

Just follow this link https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar

or if you want i can share working code with you. Good Luck.

Comment: muchas gracias. this saved me a lot of a hassle

Comment: glad i could help.

Answer (score 0):

Change 
`android:layout_height="wrap_content"` 
to 
`android:layout_height="match_parent"` 
in the outer RelativeLayout

EDIT: and then i would include the Toolbar inside the RelativeLayout.

Comment: thx you, your answer helped me understand some details i wasnt aware of.